# Maintaining a boilerplate framework and spinoff sites

Tags: git

I am looking for the best way to maintain a framework via GIT, which allows an initial cloning and subsequent incremental updates, but is otherwise separate from the cloned projects.

NB: A partial response is also welcome. Thanks in advance.

1) The Framework is cloned to a new local Project A. Changes are done on Project A, but these are not pushed back to the Framework repos, but possibly to another repos.

Q: What is the best way to work with Project A and still keep tracking for Framework changes, which could be pulled into Project A. New repos, branching or both?

2) The Framework is updated and changes are available to pull into Project A.

Q: What is the best way to handle incremental updates from the Framework repos into Project A?

3) The Framework contains example code in the file "routes", these are intended to be overwritten in Project A.

Q: How to avoid conflicts in Project A when pulling updates from the Framework?

Comment: This is vendor branch/local branch + merge as needed territory.

Answer (score 0):

Typically, you would:

- clone the Framework repo, start modifying it and push to your new project repo
- add the framework repo URL as `upstream` remote

That is:

```
git remote rename origin upstream
git remote add origin /url/new/project
```

From there, you can easily fetch new commits from Framework 'upstream' (git fetch upstream), see if they are important, and cherry-pick the ones you want, while leaving the rest.

In short, don't merge directly branches from Framework to your project.